# Passing a template into custom knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, requirejs, knockout-3.2

I would like to make a popover (bootstrap) custom binding.

I have defined this like so:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor)
        {
            var template = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor);

            $(element).popover({
                placement: 'top',
                html: true,
                content: 'text!' + template() <---- How can i get html into here?
            });
        }
    };

   <button data-bind="popover: 'templates/mytemplate.html'">
      PopOver
   </button>
```

The issue is, I'm not sure how to inject the html i want. Naturally i'd like a template path to be resolved but working with requires text! plugin is not going as well as I had hope.

I suspect I am overlooking something much more simple?

Comment: Unrelated to your stated problem. You're unwrapping the wrong thing in your custom binding. You should be unwrapping the return value of the valueAccessor function, not the valueAccessor itself.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make an ajax request to your template

```
$.ajax(template).done(function (templateData) {
    $(element).popover({
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        content: templateData
        });
 });
```

Comment: Note that in this case, you need to change `ko.unwrap(valueAccessor)` to `ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())`

Answer (score 0):

Right now your template is the literal string 'templates/mytemplate.html'. That's probably not what you want, you want the text in that file. Use something like [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) to synchronously get the text from that file.

If you intend to pass the path of your html into your binding you may want to change the variable name from template to path.